# "Error: unknown type name" - Using a struct alias within function declaration

Tags: c, struct, include

In the file: "priority_queue.h", I have defined the struct:

```
#include "astar.h"
typedef struct p_q{
struct astar_node* first;
struct astar_node* last;
int size;
 }P_Q;
```

The file "astar.h" looks like this:

```
#include "priority_queue.h"

typedef struct astar_node{
struct astar_node* next;
struct astar_node* prev;
struct astar_node* PQ_next;
struct astar_node* PQ_prev;
int x;
int y;
int c;
int h;
int tot_cost;
}Astar_node;

int func(P_Q* P);
```

Why do I get the error: "Unknown typename 'P_Q' ?

If i redefine "funk()" to :

```
 int func(struct p_q* P);
```

the error disappears but i get the warning:"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
'struct p_q' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration"

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Where is `struct astar_node` defined?

Comment: in the header "astar.h" - This header is also included in "priority_queue.h"

the function:
    int func(P_Q* P) 
is implemented in "priority_queue.c" - There are no errors connected to the type "P_Q" in the implementation

Comment: So `priority_queue.h` includes `astar.h` **and** `astar.h` includes `priority_queue.h`, right? Sounds problematic.

Comment: That is correct. My intuition is that since I need "P_Q" in astar.h, I must include priority_queue.h in astar.h , and since I need "struct astar_node" in priority_queue.h I must include astar.h

Comment: Circular includes shall be avoided. Instead you can use a forward declaration in `priority_queue.h`, i.e. instead of including `astart.h`, try `struct astar_node;` before defining `P_Q`

Comment: Please edit your quest to show that you include `astar.h` in `priority_queue.h` That's important info

Comment: So I sould not include "astar.h" in "priority_queue.h". What about the other way?

And if i want to give struct astar_node the same alias in priority_queue.h as in astar.h, is this the right way?

    struct astar_node ;

    typedef struct astar_node Astar_node;  ?

Comment: There is nothing in priority_queue.h that requires you to #include astar.h.  You can have struct pointers without knowing the struct contents.  If you find that you have two files that need to each #include the other, it's a pretty clear indication that your code is badly structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your includes are circular, i.e `priority_queue.h` includes `astar.h` which includes `priority_queue.h`. That is something you should avoid.

Try changing:

```
#include "astar.h"
typedef struct p_q{
    struct astar_node* first;
    struct astar_node* last;
    int size;
} P_Q;
```

into

```
// Forward declaration
struct astar_node;

typedef struct p_q{
    struct astar_node* first;
    struct astar_node* last;
    int size;
} P_Q;
```

You can do this because you only use **pointers** to `struct astar_node` inside `priority_queue.h`. So the compiler doesn't need to know what is inside `struct astar_node`. All it needs to know is that there is a struct named `astar_node` somewhere in your project.